# What is a valid email address for the input type email for HTML5?

Tags: html

I was wondering what is a valid email address for the input type=email for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the definition used by w3](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#form.data.emailaddress).

`joe@example.com` is a valid email address for the input type=email for HTML5.

Comment: but what does that mean in simple terms?

Comment: @Allone: I'm sure you have used email before, so you probably have at least an intuitive knowledge of email addresses?

Comment: In case that page changes, it says "any string which matches the following regular expression:

``/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/``  Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/gGQUD7/1

Answer (score 1):

a valid email in input type=email, is anything that matches the user/default set pattern

default pattern is: 1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str 1*( "." ldh-str )

refer to the spec for details - http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/input.email.html

Answer (score 0):

Any string which passes the regular expression test for

```
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```